# Assigning values to elements in html/php

Tags: php

Good evening, here is what I am trying to achieve, I currently have a web form that looks like this

```
<form id="Submit" method="post" action="FormSubmit.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /> 
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
Address line 1:  <input type="text" name="add1" /> <br />
Address Line 2:  <input type="text" name="add2" /><br />
Postcode:  <input type="text" name="postcode" /><br />
Email:  <input type="text" name="email" />
Telephone:  <input type="text" name="telephone" /><br />
<p>How would you like to be contacted <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="email" /> Email
<input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="sms" /> SMS
<input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="post" /> post <br />
<br />

Select Trainers
<select name="trainers"> 
<option value="nike">Nike</option>
<option value="adidas">Adidas</option>
<option value="rebok">Rebok</option>
</select> <br />
<br />
Select Extras
<select name="extras"> 
<option value="Laces">Laces</option>
<option value="In-souls">In-souls</option>
<option value="Shoe Polish">Polish</option>
</select> <br />
<br  />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
</form>
```

which is linked to a php script here

```
<?php
    {
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  echo "Firstname $firstname <br />\n";
 }

 {
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  echo "Lastname $lastname <br />\n";
 }

  {
  $add1 = $_POST['add1'];
  echo "$add1 <br />\n";
 }

 {
  $add2 = $_POST['add2'];
  echo "$add2 <br />\n";
 }
  {
  $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
  echo "$postcode <br />\n";
  }
  {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  echo "Contact Email Address $email <br />\n";
  }
  {
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
  echo "Contact Telephone Number $telephone <br />\n";
  }
  {
  $contact = $_POST['contact'];
  echo "You would like to be contacted by $contact <br />\n";
  }

  {
  $trainers = $_POST['trainers'];
  echo "The trainers you would like are $trainers <br />\n";
  }

  {
  $extras = $_POST['extras'];
  echo "The extras you would like are $extras <br />\n";
  }

?>
```

what I would like to do is when a shoe i.e nike is selected from the drop down box in the web form is can be assigned an int for example 30 (for £30) and then an option eg laces for (£5) therefore when the the user clicks submit the resulting php page is able to display a total of £35 but I have no idea where to start or what to search for as a number of google searches have come back unsuccessful

many thanks

Comment: That's wrong, on oh so many levels! What is with the nested code that has not purpose? You could remove all curly brackets and get the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up a mapping of values to cost...

```
$extras = array(
      'Laces' => 5,
      'Shoe Polish' => 10
);
```

...and then on form submit...

```
$runningCost = 0;

$extra = $_POST['extras'];

if (in_array($extra, $extras)) {
    $runningCost = $extras[$extra];
}
```

Comment: would it be the same for the actual shoes?

Comment: @Chris Same sort of thing, yes.

Comment: does this go in the HTML or the PHP file?